# Can we prove the formula for surface of revolution?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is math. We like to prove things. However, proofs are rigorous processes (for a good reason) and are more than just "that idea looks like it could make sense".

I've seen proofs for many different things, including in calculus, but I have yet to come across a proof for the formula of the surface of revolution

$$
A=2\pi\int_{a}^{b}y\,
\sqrt{\,1 + \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{\vphantom{\large A}2}\,}\,
\,{\rm d}x
$$

It obviously "makes sense", when you think about how you're unwrapping thin rectangular strips from the circles and adding them all up. However, that doesn't seem to be a very rigorous and indisputable proof! Right, it's worked so far, *but how are we so sure that it always will?*

Wikipedia says nothing for both volume and surface of solids of revolution. I've been around on Google, and there's still no evidence of a proof (although it might just be buried under all that math help for Calculus students...)

Comment: The first problem is to establish what you're even trying to prove. You want to prove that that formula gives the area of the surface, but what does that mean? If that isn't your *definition* of area, what is?

Comment: Even if we treat that formula as a definition, we can't just invent a formula completely and claim that it works. In middle school terms, when I paint the solid I will either run out of paint or have some left over unless I have the correct formula! So there must be some other defining element, and my implied question is... what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can approximate a circle by regular polygons.

In particular, instead of a revolution surface, we take a "polygonal surface" whose section is a regular polygon. As an example, the vase in this picture:
[image]

Now, the vase is made of strips which are actually unrollable. Their width is the side of the polygon, given by (see image below)
$$
s = 2a\,\tan \bigg( \frac{\pi}{n} \bigg),
$$

where $n$ is the number of sides of the polygon (for a hexagon, 6).

[image]

The height of the strip is the length of the light brown lines on the vase above, which is simply the length of the curve given by:
$$
h=\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{da}{dz} \bigg)^2}\,dz,
$$

where the apothem now depends on $z$ (which is what you called $x$). 
(I hope you are familiar with the arc length formula.)

The area of a strip is therefore:
$$
\int_{0}^h s\,dh = \int_{z_1}^{z_2} 2a(z)\,\tan \bigg( \frac{\pi}{n} \bigg)\sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{da}{dz} \bigg)^2}\,dz.
$$

Since we have $n$ strips, the area of the total surface is then:
$$
A = 2n\tan \bigg( \frac{\pi}{n} \bigg) \int_{z_1}^{z_2} a(z)\,\sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{da}{dz} \bigg)^2}\,dz.
$$

Now take the *revolution* surface $S$. We approximate it with 2 polygonal surfaces of $n$ strips, *one inscribed* ($I_n$) and *one circumscribed* ($C_n$). For each $n$, we can write that (can you see why?):
$$
I_n \le S \le C_n.
$$

Using the formula above, for the circumscribed surface the apothem is simply the radius, so:
$$
C_n = 2n\tan \bigg( \frac{\pi}{n} \bigg) \int_{z_1}^{z_2} r(z)\,\sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{dr}{dz} \bigg)^2}\,dz.
$$

For the inscribed one, it is easy to see (look again at the second picture) that the apothem is:
$$
a = r\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi}{n}\bigg),
$$

so:
$$
I_n = C_n\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi}{n}\bigg).
$$

Now we have that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} C_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 2n \tan \bigg( \frac{\pi}{n}\bigg) \int\dots = 2\pi \int\dots
$$

and $I_n$ has the same limit, as $\cos(\pi/n)\to 1$. Since $I_n\le S\le C_n$, it must be then that:
$$
S = 2\pi \int_{z_1}^{z_2} r(z)\,\sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{dr}{dz} \bigg)^2}\,dz.
$$

Comment: I'm going to need a little time to interpret that (nothing I don't understand, just want to make sure I get it). However, aren't you running into the same problem of unraveling like the sphere? The long strips in the hexagon above aren't unrollable without calculus (so it'll work, but it's not geometrically provable). I realise I'm being picky but it's the point of the question after all... :)

Comment: The strips are flat, so are unrollable, that's the whole point. And their area is simply the integral of their breadth, as in "integral is the area under the curve".

Comment: With "flat" I mean intrinsically, like cylinders and cones.

Comment: Ok, it just doesn't look like it is from the picture but if I think about it I can make it using paper without bending it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you accept the definition of area of a general surface $S$ parametrized by $u$ and $v$:
$$
A = \int_S \bigg| \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial v} \bigg|\,du\,dv,
$$

(this one makes "a lot" of intuitive sense if you think of the area of a parallelogram), you can recover your formula as a special case.

Let's move to polar coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$. Now for a surface of revolution, the surface is given simply by $r(z)$, and $r$ does not depend on $\theta$.

The simplest way to substitute is to take $u=\theta$ and $v=z$.

Now $\vec x= (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, z)$, so (remember that $r$ is a function of $z$!):
$$
\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial \theta} = (-r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta, 0),
$$

and:
$$
\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial z} = \bigg(\frac{dr}{dz}\cos\theta,\frac{dr}{dz}\sin\theta,1\bigg).
$$

We get ($\cos^2+\sin^2=1$):
$$
\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial z}  = \bigg( r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, -r\frac{dr}{dz} \bigg),
$$

so:
$$
\bigg|\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial z} \bigg| = \sqrt{r^2 + \bigg(r\frac{dr}{dz}\bigg)^2} = r\sqrt{1+\bigg(\frac{dr}{dz}\bigg)^2}.
$$

We can finally put it in the integral:
$$
A=\int_a^b\int_0^{2\pi} r\sqrt{1+\bigg(\frac{dr}{dz}\bigg)^2}\,d\theta\,dz.
$$

The integrand does not depend on $\theta$, so it becomes:
$$
A=2\pi\int_a^b r\sqrt{1+\bigg(\frac{dr}{dz}\bigg)^2}\,dz.
$$

If you call $r\to y$ and $z\to x$, you get exactly the integral you are asking.

Comment: +1 (if I were allowed) for the neat help, but is there really no way to get rid of the "if you accept the definition that"?

Comment: It is the *unique* definition that satisfies all the properties you want the area to have. To know if it's good for you, let's see...what are the properties you think an area should have?

Comment: I don't know, I've never sat down and thought about this stuff (it just sort of worked)... maybe the space it covers when unrolled? It's just hard to imagine for things that aren't easy to unroll.

Comment: Uhm...unrolling doesn't work well, as *actually* curved surfaces (say, a sphere, not a cylinder) need to be metrically deformed to be "unrolled" (think of Earth projections)...

Comment: I have another idea (for the revolution surface case). I'm writing another answer.

Comment: @geodude I sense by the way you say "the unique way" that this cross product falls out of Fubini's theorem applied to the Lebesgue measure, which indeed provides the unique natural definition of area, in the same way that Cavalieri's principle falls out of Fubini's theorem. I can't quite see how to make it work however, since the surface is some subset of $\Bbb R^2$ embedded in $\Bbb R^3$

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **Pappus's centroid theorem**. Centroid, because we calculate the distance that is traveled by the geometric center, or centroid, of the curve, in order to calculate the solid of revolution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem